# Using Arrays in MySQLi And PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Following is a typical OOP way to Connect and Retrive data from MySQL database using MySQLi and PHP.
Now I am a little bit confused on using the pure PHP arrays at this example:

Can some one please let me know if the `$result` is array or not? I mean in

```
$result = $mysqli_coonect->query($sql);
```

if so how come we didn't use the `array()` function or `[]` to create it?!

same thing happening with `$row` at:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

I am asking this because in order to load `$row;` to `$results[]` at `$results[] = $row;` we declared the `$results` as an array explicitly before the `while()` how come we are not doing this for other or vice versa?!

```
<?php
$mysqli_coonect = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id <= 10";    
$result = $mysqli_coonect->query($sql);
if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0))
{
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
  $result->free();
}
$mysqli_coonect->close();
```

Comment: `array()` isn't technically a function -- it's one of those syntax oddities, like many other 'language constructs' which are specifically not-functions, but look like them (e.g. `list()`)

Comment: Hi Josh can you please take a look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp

Comment: that's just one of many reasons not to treat w3schools like an authority. Refer to php.net first for any PHP definitions you need, and MDN for javascript. That `array()` looks like, and is occasionally referred to as a function is more a historical quirk than anything else. If you try and use it like it's a function, you're going to have a bad time. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php#refsect1-function.array-notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always refer to the PHP documentation. It's great and you can easily find what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php states that a query will return `mixed` in this case meaning either `false` if the query failed or `mysqli_result` object of the query was successful.

---

**Getting down to business**

1. `$result = $mysqli->query($query)` returns a `mysqli_result` object. This means that `$result` is now an object.
2. We then call the method `fetch_assoc` from our newly created `$result` (mysqli_result) object and store the results of the method in the variable `$row` (which if the method is successful will be an array). If you look at what `fetch_assoc` returns (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) you see that it returns an `array`.
3. We loop through our newly created $row array.

Comment: I started typing out a longer answer, but I agree in this case the best advice is to rtfm.

Comment: Thanks dojs but I dint get anything from the link and your comment!

Comment: Okay, well try to follow the steps now and see if it makes any sense.

Comment: so in step 2 is the `$row` still object or array?

Comment: $row becomes an array because the method fetch_assoc returns an array

Comment: and just one final question?

Comment: Sure, I could go into greater detail if something is confusing you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72863/discussion-between-dojs-and-behseini).

Comment: Why the `$results = $row;` not working as `$results[] = $row;`? I mean if we can reference arrays like` $test = $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");` why the `$results = $row;`  returns only the lasr row of the database?